# Why is assert_called_with failing to pass?

Tags: mocking, patch, python-2.6

I am having a lot of difficulty setting my unit test.  I have been using patch but it is not behaving entirely as expected.

I have a decorator at the top of my test function:

`@mock.patch('WarningFactory.WarningAPIUpdate')
@mock.patch('WarningFactory.SomethingElse')
def test_send_tc_update(self, other_mock, api_mock):`

However when at the end of my function when I try to make the following assertion:

`api_mock.send_warning.assert_called_with('IDQ20026', 'IDQ20026')`

It fails

I know that is should pass because I run

`print api_mock.mock_calls`

giving

`[call(u'test_api'),
 call().send_warning('IDQ20026', 'IDQ20026'),
 call().send_warning('IDQ24500', 'IDQ24500')]`

I can clearly see the send_warning method being called with the correct values, so why is my assertion failing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  Having the same issue

Comment: @learningKnight Added an answer, hope that helps.

Comment: for the poor souls who wrote `assert myfunc.assert_called_with(...)` just remember to remove the `assert` and write it instead as `myfunc.assert_called_with(...)` (omitting the preceding `assert`)

Comment: @Marc I was the poor soul! OMG being new in Python unit testing, I almost lost all hairs I had left with the `assert` which was not needed / wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Looking back now the problem was that assert_called_with only checks the most recent call.

> assert_any_call(*args, **kwargs)¶ assert the mock has been called with
>   the specified arguments.
>
> The assert passes if the mock has ever been called, unlike
>   assert_called_with() and assert_called_once_with() that only pass if
>   the call is the most recent one, and in the case of
>   assert_called_once_with() it must also be the only call.

- from https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

The docs are a little dodgy as they don't mention this under the assert_called_with method.

I ended up using the assert_any_call method for my tests.

Comment: Didn't help me, but kudos to you for coming back regardless

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem as well! I had even reread the docs to make sure that assert_called_with can verify more than the most recent call, but I missed the truth somehow. I do recall that I was being linked to 2 different doc pages on mock, both under Python 3, but structured very differently. That was leading to some inconsistent reading on my part.

Answer (score 0):

If [user3559247's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728565/1389817) does not work, it may be that you're trying to mock nested objects and you will need to read about [chaining mock calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-chained-calls). In my case, I wanted to test this code in a hypothetical class `MyAzureBatchClient` that leverages the Azure Python SDK:

```
def node_counts():
  self.batch_client = azure.batch.batch_service_client.BatchServiceClient(...)
  self.batch_client.account.list_pool_node_counts()
  ...
```

Calling `mocked_batch_client.account.list_pool_node_counts.assert_called_with()` failed, although checking the `mock_calls` property would showed something similar to you:

```
[call().list_pool_node_counts()]
```

However when properly chaining with `mocked_batch_client.return_value.account.list_pool_node_counts.assert_called_with()` it works as expected. When checking `mocked_batch_client.return_value.account.mock_calls`, note how `call.method` is present instead of `call().method`:
[call.list_pool_node_counts()]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the print output you mentioned the syntax should probably be:

```
api_mock.return_value.send_warning.assert_called_with('IDQ20026', 'IDQ20026')
```

Notice the **call()**.`send_warning('IDQ20026', 'IDQ20026')` prefix, which correlates to `.return_value`.

But why work so hard? I wrote a [helper library](https://pypi.org/project/mock-generator/) to automatically generate the asserts for me.

Just add those lines to print the correct asserts for your case:

```
import mock_autogen.generator
print(mock_autogen.generator.generate_asserts(api_mock))
```